# Почему не могу получить значение в SQL?

Tags: mysql

Субд: MySQL 8.0.27.

Есть таблица: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть коэффициент **1.09**.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Почему не могу фильтровать по нему?**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Во-первых, глупо сравнивать число и строку. Уберите кавычки. Во-вторых, FLOAT хранит не точное, а приблизительное значение, и сравнение с точным значением запросто может не выполняться. Смените тип на DECIMAL.

Comment: @Akina, ориентируюсь по языкам программирования. Для чисел с плавающей точкой в MySQL стоит использовать DECIMAL?

Comment: Для точных нецелых значений следует использовать DECIMAL.